# Filtering list based on value selected from drop down is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Initially when the page loads,

I have a drop down which by default has a place holder "Select Person Type" (empty value text as shown in the code)..and a check box list which by default displays all the persons.

Based on the value selected from dropdown, I created a angular filter to display only that type of persons (Which is working perfect), but once i filter based on type and if i select placeholder "Select Person Type" the checkbox list is empty.

```
<select class="form-control" id="personId" data-ng-model="personModel.personTypeID" name="selectPersonType"
           ng-options="person.personTypeUniqueID as person.personTypeEn for person in personTypes | orderBy:'personTypeEn' ">
            <option value="">Select person type</option><br/></select><div ng-repeat="person in persons|orderBy:'name'|filter: { personTypeID: personModel.PersonTypeID }|filter:searchperson" style="display:flex;padding-left:5px">
            <input style="min-width:13px !important;" class="checkbox" id={{person.personUniqueId}} type="checkbox" ng-checked="selectedOptionPerson.indexOf(person.personUniqueId)> -1" ng-click="toggleSelection($event)" ng-model="option.optionPersonModel[$index]">{{person.name}}
        </div>
```

Reason I think its happening because is Im filtering based on PersonTypeID and the placeholder doesn't have any such ID.

Is there any way that i can display the whole list of persons when I select placeholder again?

Explanation: I wanna display all the persons when I select the place holder after I filtered using person type.

Thank you for your time...any suggestions might help.

Comment: can you please post your code for better understanding or a plunkr might help

Comment: @WasimMulla here is the updated question

Comment: @WasimMulla please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the ng-options directive on the select and a filter with a [predicate](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/filter/filter) function.

> function(value, index): A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The function is called for each element of array. The final result is an array of those elements that the predicate returned true for.

In my predicate function I check if the selected value is not `null` (Please Select), else I check if the current item in the list matches the selected value

You can view a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/5m49Lo7k/1/)

Please see code below:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="PeopleController">
    <select data-ng-options="employmentType.id as employmentType.descr for employmentType in employmentTypes" data-ng-model="selectedEmploymentTypeId">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
    </select>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="person in people | filter:getFilter">
            {{person.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
controller('PeopleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [{
      name: 'John Doe',
      employmentTypeId: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Jane Doe',
      employmentTypeId: 2
    }, {
      name: 'Santa Claus',
      employmentTypeId: 3
   }];

 $scope.employmentTypes = [{
     id: 1,
     descr: 'Permanent'
   }, {
     id: 2,
     descr: 'Temporary'
   }, {
     id: 3,
     descr: 'Casual'
   }];

 $scope.getFilter = function(value, index) {    
    if ($scope.selectedEmploymentTypeId === null || $scope.selectedEmploymentTypeId === undefined) {
        return true;
    }
    return (value.employmentTypeId === $scope.selectedEmploymentTypeId);
 };
}])
```

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt thanks for the fiddler...helped a lot..now i see the blank check box list when the page loads and when i select a person type it works, and then if i come back and select place holder...it works again (Displaying all the persons)...but its empty when the page loads..any suggestions

Comment: It should work when the page loads, as the example fiddle does. Are you not setting the default value of the selected item in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Remove value="" from the place holder.

Because When you select placeholder, its filtering with empty value instead of filtering with all persons.

Comment: I tried using <option value="Select Person type"></option>...It's not working

Comment: try like this <option>Select person type</option>

Answer (score -1):

```
data-ng-change="toggleSelection(id)"
```

use this.

Comment: This is not a adequate answer. Please add relevant code and explanation.

Comment: Code only answers are very likely to be unhelpful for future visitors and even the OP himself. Consider editing your answer to contain explaination with the code.